# Compare two XMLs

Tags: c#, xml

I am pretty new to comparing the xmls in c#. Can somebody suggest me a easy and performant way to do the same. Below is my requirement.

Source XML file:

```
<a>
 <b>hello</b>
<c>
<d>
 <e>abcd</e>
</d>
</c>
<f>image1</f>
</a>
```

Destination XML file:

```
<a>
 <b1>hello</b1>
<c>
<d>
 <e>thguh</e>
</d>
</c>
<f>image2</f>
</a>
```

In the xml files as for  tag, i don't want to see it as difference as it is intended. Hence i want to filter out such differences and see if there are any other differences like node values and node names. Comparing  node values and filtering the image value changes and finally telling the differences is my priority.

Comment: You can parse XMLs, throw away non-relevant data from both XMLs, and then compare, for example.

Answer (score 3):

you can use XMLDiff to compare the xml files [XML Differance and compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

```
   XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                            XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                            XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
```

then compare

```
 bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, newFile, false, diffgramWriter);
   diffgramWriter.Close();
```

Comment: I already tried that but it isn't telling me the node name changes. I need node name changes as well.